# How does a pytorch dataset object know whether it has hit the end when used in a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, iterator, pytorch

I am writing a custom pytorch dataset. In `__init__` the dataset object loads a file that contains certain data. But in my program I only wish to access part of the data (to achieve train/valid cut, if it helps). Originally I thought this behavior was controlled by overriding `__len__`, but it turned out that modifying `__len__` does not help. A simple example is as follows:

```
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import torch

class NewDS(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = torch.randn(10,2) # suppose there are 10 items in the data file
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)-5 # But I only want to access the first 5 items
        
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data[index]

ds = NewDS()
for i, x in enumerate(ds):
    print(i)
```

The output is 0 through 9, while the desired behavior would be 0 through 4.

How does this dataset object know that the enumeration has hit the end when used in a for loop like this? Any other method to achieve a similar effect is also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`torch.utils.data.Subset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Subset) to get subset of your data

```
top_five = torch.utils.data.Subset(ds, indices=range(5))  # Get first five items
for i, x in enumerate(top_five):
    print(i)
0
1
2
3
4
```

---

[`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) in loop will return item until it gets [`StopIteration`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration) exception.

```
len(ds)         # Returned modified length
5

# `enumerate` will call `next` method on iterable each time in loop.
#  and When no more data available a StopIteration exception is raised instead.
iter_ds = iter(ds)
print(next(iter_ds))
print(next(iter_ds))
print(next(iter_ds))
print(next(iter_ds))
print(next(iter_ds))
print(next(iter_ds))
print(next(iter_ds))
print(next(iter_ds))
print(next(iter_ds))
print(next(iter_ds))

print(next(iter_ds))  #11th time StopIteration exception raised as no item left to iterate in iterable
```

Output:

```
tensor([-1.5952, -0.0826])
tensor([-2.2254,  0.2461])
tensor([-0.8268,  0.1956])
tensor([ 0.3157, -0.3403])
tensor([0.8971, 1.1255])
tensor([0.3922, 1.3184])
tensor([-0.4311, -0.8898])
tensor([ 0.1128, -0.5708])
tensor([-0.5403, -0.9036])
tensor([0.6550, 1.6777])

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-99-7a9910e027c3> in <module>
     10 print(next(iter_ds))
     11 
---> 12 print(next(iter_ds))  #11th time StopIteration exception raised as no item left to iterate

StopIteration:
```

Comment: Thanks. But I would still like to know the internal mechanism of what happens when I use my dataset in a for-loop as above. It's been bugging me for a while.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a custom dataloader with `Dataset` class, while you are enumerating it with for the loop. It is not how it works. For enumerating you have to pass the `Dataset` to `DataLoader` class. your code will work great like this,

```
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import torch

class NewDS(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = torch.randn(10,2) # suppose there are 10 items in the data file
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)-5 # But I only want to access the first 5 items
        
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data[index]

ds = NewDS()
for i, x in range(len(ds)): #if you do dont want to use DataLoader, then dont use enumerate
    print(i, ds[i])
#output 
tensor([-0.2351,  1.3037])
tensor([ 0.4032, -0.2739])
tensor([-0.5687, -0.7300])
tensor([0.5418, 0.8572])
tensor([ 1.9973, -0.2939])

dl = DataLoader(ds, batch_size=1) # pass the ds object to DataLoader 

for i, x in enumerate(dl): # now you can use enumarate
    print(i, x)
#output
tensor([-0.2351,  1.3037])
tensor([ 0.4032, -0.2739])
tensor([-0.5687, -0.7300])
tensor([0.5418, 0.8572])
tensor([ 1.9973, -0.2939])
```

Further details can be read at this official [pytorch tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html).